# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan"

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-cascade

I am trying to copy a persistent object and modifies it, and then persists (
insert new record), but not work!

E.g.:

The objcet  A(Persistent) 
The object B = copy (A) 
modify B 
insert B / / Error

Following fragments of my code, thank anyway!

mapping:

```
@Table(name="rbatb02_roteiro_modelo",schema="rbasm001")
public class ModeloRoteiroVO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8184929358916648526L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="rbasq02_rbatb02_roteiro_modelo", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)   
    @SequenceGenerator(name="rbasq02_rbatb02_roteiro_modelo",schema="rbasm001",sequenceName="rbasq02_rbatb02_roteiro_modelo",allocationSize=1)  
    @Column(name="nu_roteiro_modelo")
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name="nu_roteiro_copiado",referencedColumnName="nu_roteiro_modelo")
    @OneToOne
    private ModeloRoteiroVO  modeloRoteiroPai; 

    @JoinColumn(name="nu_perfil",referencedColumnName="nu_perfil")
    @ManyToOne
    private PerfilVO perfil;

    @Column(name="no_roteiro", length=100)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="de_roteiro",length=255)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name="ic_publicado",length=1)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SituacaoModeloRoteiroEnum situacaoModeloRoteiro;    

    @Column(name="IC_TIPO_MODELO",length=1)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoModeloRoteiroEnum tipoModeloRoteiro;    

    @Column(name="nu_versao")
    private Long numeroVersao;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="modeloRoteiro",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)   
    private List<ModeloFaseVO> fases;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="modeloRoteiro",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<MensagemModeloRoteiroVO> mensagensModelosRoteiro;


    public ModeloRoteiroVO() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }       

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof ModeloRoteiroVO)) {
            return false;
        }
        ModeloRoteiroVO objConvertido = (ModeloRoteiroVO) obj;
        return this.getId().equals(objConvertido.getId());    

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ModeloRoteiroVO getModeloRoteiroPai() {
        return modeloRoteiroPai;
    }

    public void setModeloRoteiroPai(ModeloRoteiroVO modeloRoteiroPai) {
        this.modeloRoteiroPai = modeloRoteiroPai;
    }

    public PerfilVO getPerfil() {
        return perfil;
    }

    public void setPerfil(PerfilVO perfil) {
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public TipoModeloRoteiroEnum getTipoModeloRoteiro() {
        return tipoModeloRoteiro;
    }

    public void setTipoModeloRoteiro(TipoModeloRoteiroEnum tipoModeloRoteiro) {
        this.tipoModeloRoteiro = tipoModeloRoteiro;
    }

    public Long getNumeroVersao() {
        return numeroVersao;
    }

    public void setNumeroVersao(Long numeroVersao) {
        this.numeroVersao = numeroVersao;
    }

    public List<ModeloFaseVO> getFases() {
        return fases;
    }

    public void setFases(List<ModeloFaseVO> fases) {
        this.fases = fases;
    }

    public List<MensagemModeloRoteiroVO> getMensagensModelosRoteiro() {
        return mensagensModelosRoteiro;
    }

    public void setMensagensModelosRoteiro(
            List<MensagemModeloRoteiroVO> mensagensModelosRoteiro) {
        this.mensagensModelosRoteiro = mensagensModelosRoteiro;
    }

    public SituacaoModeloRoteiroEnum getSituacaoModeloRoteiro() {
        return situacaoModeloRoteiro;
    }

    public void setSituacaoModeloRoteiro(
            SituacaoModeloRoteiroEnum situacaoModeloRoteiro) {
        this.situacaoModeloRoteiro = situacaoModeloRoteiro;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ModeloRoteiro [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}



@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public ModeloRoteiroVO copiarModeloDeRoteiroEmModoTransiente(
            ModeloRoteiroVO modeloRoteiroVO)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        ModeloRoteiroVO modeloPai = this.findById(modeloRoteiroVO.getId()); 
        //sobrescrever id para nulo
        modeloRoteiroVO.setId(null);
        modeloRoteiroVO.setModeloRoteiroPai(modeloPai);
List<ModeloFaseVO> listaAux = new ArrayList<ModeloFaseVO>(modeloRoteiroVO.getFases());

        for (ModeloFaseVO fase : listaAux) {            
            //sobrescrever id
            fase.setId(null);
List<ModeloAtividadeVO> listaAuxAtiv=new ArrayList<ModeloAtividadeVO(fase.getAtividades());

            for (ModeloAtividadeVO modeloAtividadeVO : listaAuxAtiv) {                      
                                 //sobrescrever id
                modeloAtividadeVO.setId(null);      
List<OpcaoRespostaAtividadeVO> opcoes = new ArrayList<OpcaoRespostaAtividadeVO>(modeloAtividadeVO.getOpcaoRespostaAtividades());
                for (OpcaoRespostaAtividadeVO opcaoResposta : opcoes) {
                                         //sobrescrever id para nulo
                    opcaoResposta.setId(null);

                }
                modeloAtividadeVO.setOpcaoRespostaAtividades(opcoes);

            }

            fase.setAtividades(listaAuxAtiv);
        }
        modeloRoteiroVO.setFases(listaAux);
List<MensagemModeloRoteiroVO> listaAuxMensagem = new ArrayList<MensagemModeloRoteiroVO>(modeloRoteiroVO.getMensagensModelosRoteiro());

        for (MensagemModeloRoteiroVO mensagemModeloRoteiroVO : listaAuxMensagem) {
            mensagemModeloRoteiroVO.setId(null);
        }
        modeloRoteiroVO.setMensagensModelosRoteiro(listaAuxMensagem);
        return modeloRoteiroVO;
    }

public void publicar(ModeloRoteiroVO modeloRoteiroVO){

    modeloRoteiroVO = saveImpl(modeloRoteiroVO);
}


ModeloRoteiroVO copia =service.copiarModeloDeRoteiroEmModoTransiente(getInstance());//managed
service.publicar(copia);//Error
```

stack trace:

> ```
> Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
>     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
>     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>     ... 89 more
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan": br.gov.caixa.gitecsa.vo.ModeloFaseVO.fases
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1481) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
>     ... 92 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan": br.gov.caixa.gitecsa.vo.ModeloFaseVO.fases
>     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.prepareCollectionForUpdate(Collections.java:241) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:201) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:59) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:225) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
>     ... 98 more
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy an existing entity - modify it - and save it as new entity, then you need to deep copy that object.

You can do deep copy of a object by Serializing and then De-Serializing that object.

Now this new object would just be a copy and will not have any reference to the original object. You can modify this new copy and insert again.

Code to do deepcopy,

```
public Object deepCopy(Object input) {

    Object output = null;
    try {
        // Writes the object
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(input);

        // Reads the object
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        output = objectInputStream.readObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```